# printarea function not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to print a particular area on my webpage by using jQuery `printarea()` function. It doesn't work and returns an error.
and its shows error like tolowerCase is undefined
*Error*

> return (media.toLowerCase() == "" || media.toLowerCase() == "print")

*jQuery*

```
function printDiv() {
    $('#dvTokenArea').printArea();
}​

<div id="dvTokenArea" runat="server">
     <asp:Label ID="lblTokenNumber" runat="server" Text="Print ME !!!!!!!!!!!!">    </asp:Label>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btnPrintToken" runat="server" Text="Print"
     OnClientClick="javascript:printDiv();" />​
```

Comment: return (media.toLowerCase() == "" || media.toLowerCase() == "print")
 got it on firebug on mozilla firefox browser

Comment: also am using modalpopupextender ajax control...print button is on popupextender also the div whose html i want to print

Comment: What is `$.printArea()`? I've never heard of that function. And posting the source markup and not the ASP markup would probably be more useful.

Comment: I'm guessing that's the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code in the plugin which returns the error:

```
$(document).find("link")
            .filter(function(){
                    return $(this).attr("rel").toLowerCase() == "stylesheet";
                })
            .filter(function(){ // this filter contributed by "mindinquiring"
                    var media = $(this).attr("media");
                    return (media.toLowerCase() == "" || media.toLowerCase() == "print")
                })
            .each(function(){
                    head += '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="' + $(this).attr("href") + '" >';
                });
```

You haven't given enough information to be certain but I believe that you have no `media` attribute on your `link` elements and you are using JQuery 1.6 or above which returns `undefined` if the attribute is not set.

[From the attr documentation:](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set.

So, if you have no `media` attribute set on your `link` elements whose `rel` attribute is set to `stylesheet`, `toLowerCase()` will be called on media which is `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct in pointing out the error but what is the exact solution should i use jquery version less than 1.6

Comment: @daljeet Set the media attribute of the link elements wherever the rel="stylesheet". Don't downgrade the jquery version.

Comment: better yet just replace the bug in that line with:
    `return (typeof media == "undefined" || media.toLowerCase() == "" || media.toLowerCase() == "print");`
there are a few forks of this plugin you can find around in github.

Answer (score 2):

As Pencho Ilchev referred, this is caused by the jQuery 1.6 BC break of .attr(). Here is a fixed fork of the PrintArea plugin:

https://github.com/djozsef/jquery.printarea.js

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.